# Use .unwrap to unwrap the children of all divs with a specified class

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use the `.unwrap` function to unwrap all instances of a specific class (in this case 'blah')

```
<div class="blah">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>

<div class="blah">
  <span>Testing</span>
</div>
```

Right now, I'm using a code like this:

`$('.blah a').unwrap();`

But this wouldn't unwrap the second piece of code with the `span` in it above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
$('.blah').children().unwrap();
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/KAzgq/

Answer (score 5):

I found an issue with the accepted answer to this question. jQuery's `.children()` method doesn't return any of the text nodes. Meaning that any content under the div that is not wrapped in another element will get stripped.

This is my solution:

```
$('.blah').replaceWith(function () {
    return this.childNodes;
});
```

Comment: You can use `.contents()`: `return $(this).contents()`